# Excel File Upload Working Locally But Not On Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

Using ASP.net MVC on Azure. As subject states, it's working fine locally but not on Azure. The form renders properly. Upon submitting the form, I get my page header and a message stating "An error occurred while processing your request." I've checked the database and all the fields were carried over properly. I'm not sure what else to use to troubleshoot.

```
namespace WebApplication12.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    OleDbConnection Econ;

    // GET: Dashboard
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetDirectoryName(file.FileName);
        string filepath = "/excel/" + filename;
        file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/excel/"), filename));
        InsertExcelData(filepath, filename);
        ViewBag.Message = "File successfully uploaded.";
        return View();
    }

    private void ExcelConn(string filepath)
    {
        string constr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", filepath);
        Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    }

    private void InsertExcelData(string filepath, string filename)
    {
        string fullpath = Server.MapPath("/excel/") + filename;
        ExcelConn(fullpath);
        string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", "Sheet1$");
        OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(query, Econ);
        Econ.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Econ);
        Econ.Close();
        oda.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TimeStamp", typeof(System.DateTime)));

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dr["Email"] = User.Identity.GetUserId(); 
            dr["TimeStamp"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
        objbulk.DestinationTableName = "Upload";
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", "Email");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("TimeStamp", "TimeStamp");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("EmployeeId", "EmployeeId");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Title", "Title");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Department", "Department");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Race", "Race");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Gender", "Gender");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("AnnualizedBase", "AnnualizedBase");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("AnnualizedTCC", "AnnualizedTCC");
        con.Open();
        objbulk.WriteToServer(dt);
        con.Close();


    }
}  
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a cloud environment you typically don't write to the web server file system. Rather, you save the upload off to blob storage and keep a record of the path where you saved it along with the persisted data record.

[Here is an article](https://www.wintellect.com/azure-bits-2-saving-the-image-to-azure-blob-storage/) where the author uses the Storage APIs to send an uploaded image off to a blob. But this is a rather standard challenge to solve with blob storage, so [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#upload-a-blob-into-a-container) will likely provide enough information for you to make progress. [Here is an official Microsoft sample MVC controller](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-Storage-DotNet/Controllers/HomeController.cs) that combines MVC and blob storage.